# What is the name for the design pattern that handles CRUD operations for one database table through a "manager"?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

What is the name for the design pattern that handles database tables through "managers"?

These "managers" are responsible for CRUD operations on 1 database table only. 
I'll call this pattern the "Table manager" pattern, but I guess that not proper.

So my question is: What is the name for the design pattern that handles CRUD operations for one database table through a "manager"? See picture below.

[image]

I guess it's one of these:

- Facade: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/facade
- Command: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command
- Table Module: https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableModule.html
- Table Manager: https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~antoy/Courses/Patterns/www.mindspring.net/%257Emgrand/pattern_synopses3.htm
- Data Mapper: https://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Structural/DataMapper/README.html

But I'm not sure.

Comment: [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)?

Comment: @AlexHowansky `The active record pattern is an approach to accessing data in a database. A database table or view is wrapped into a class. Thus, an object instance is tied to a single row in the table.`... yeah, I guess you are right. Thanks for you help.

Comment: an overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping (see also)

Comment: Or the [Repository Pattern](https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570556/what-are-some-good-design-patterns-for-crud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to answer my own question. The answers made by the Commentators were correct. 
I want to add that Doctrine calls this pattern the: `EntityRepository`.

Why does this matter? It is because the main project of Doctrine is ORM. Many Frameworks makes use of Doctrine ORM including: Symphony, Drupal, Laravel, PHPUnit, TYPO3.

See these links:

- https://www.doctrine-project.org/
- https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/latest/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.html

See code samples:

https://hotexamples.com/examples/doctrine.orm/EntityRepository/-/php-entityrepository-class-examples.html